# get highest date between two date column in mysql query

Tags: mysql

Hello I have two column of date time of multiple rows i want to fetch row with latest date(highest) between two column of all record. Please check below:

```
 ID|Date1                 |Date2
 1 |2021-06-10 19:03:36   |Null
 2 |2021-06-11 19:33:41   |2021-06-16 09:49:41
 3 |2021-06-16 20:04:24   |Null
```

I want to get highest date from all record of two column(Date1 and Date2). From above table, I want third row date because this is highest date(2021-06-16 20:04:24) from all record of two column. If we change the date1 column row 3 by 2021-06-16 09:20:41 then result will be row 2 because highest date record found in date2. Please help me for creating mysql query for getting full data row

Answer (score 2):

If you want only 1 row in the results and you don't care about ties, then use `GREATEST()` to get the max date in each row, sort by that max date descending and use `LIMIT 1` to pick the top row:

```
SELECT *
FROM tablename
ORDER BY GREATEST(COALESCE(Date1, '1000-01-01'), COALESCE(Date2, '1000-01-01')) DESC 
LIMIT 1
```

If `Date1` is not nullable use `COALESCE()` only for `Date2`:

```
SELECT *
FROM tablename
ORDER BY GREATEST(Date1, COALESCE(Date2, '1000-01-01')) DESC 
LIMIT 1
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=7e77bc803023747e814a93ddb74f7936).

Comment: thanks for provide usefull greatest function

Comment: @RajasthanAyurvedUniversity fine if it worked and don't forget to accept the answer by clicking on the checkmark.

Answer (score 0):

You can union the two columns and get the `MAX()`:

```
SELECT MAX(dateColumns)
FROM
    (
     SELECT DATE1 as dateColumns FROM yourtable
     UNION ALL
     SELECT DATE2 FROM yourtable
    ) sub
```

Comment: Jinx on both coming up with "yourtable" independently.  FYI: Original question is a bit contradictory on whether the whole row needs to be returned or just the max date.

Comment: That's too funny. I saw your answer come in and didn't even notice that. I agree on the ambiguity. I figure they can sort it out once they get some direction on how to identify the max.

Comment: @JNevill I want full record like id,date1,date2

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this with somewhat minimal SQL where "yourtable" is whatever the name of your table is:

```
select ID, Date1, Date2
from yourtable
where greatest(
  coalesce(Date1,'1900-01-01'), 
  coalesce(Date2,'1900-01-01')
) in (
  select max(greatest(
    coalesce(Date1,'1900-01-01'), 
    coalesce(Date2,'1900-01-01')
  )) from yourtable
)
```

However, performance of this kind of query may not scale for huge tables.  **EDIT**: Updated to include coalesce() of null dates to an arbitrarily "early" date.

Comment: I would add coalesce otherwise greatest will give null for those records where date1 or date2 is null

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out.  I will update the answer.  Is there a better value to coalesce than an arbitrarily "old" date?

Comment: I would use greatest(coalesce(date1, date2), coalesce(date2, date1)). this should be generic.